# UIView's not being added to contentView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add some views in code to the contentView of a table view cell. However nothing shows up. I get an empty cell. Below is the code of me adding subviews to the content view of a custom cell.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setupViews()

}

func setupViews() {
    //feedback_title setup
    feedback_title.text = Constants.IndividualStudiesPage.FEEDBACK_TITLE
    feedback_title.numberOfLines = 0
    feedback_title.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail

    feedback_title.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = standard_height_width

    //feedback_box setup
    feedback_box.text = Constants.IndividualStudiesPage.DEFAULT_FEEDBACK

    // TODO: Change to infinte (0) number of lines. Height constraint interferes with this
    feedback_box.numberOfLines = 2
    feedback_box.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = standard_height_width

    contentView.addSubview(feedback_title)
    contentView.addSubview(feedback_box)
}
```

Here's the interesting thing. When I add some dummy view like an empty UILabel to the content view in the storyboard, then everything shows up including the views I added in the code. Here's a picture to show you what I mean:
[image]

But when I don't add any dummy view then nothing shows up...Why and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The feedback_cell and feedback_box are instantiated like so at the top of the class

```
class FeedbackCell: UITableViewCell {

var feedback_title : UILabel = UILabel.newAutoLayoutView()
var feedback_box : UILabel = UILabel.newAutoLayoutView()
```

newAutoLayoutView is a PureLayout function that essentially just instantiates the labels to empty views. I then update the AutoLayout constraints, also using PureLayout in the updateConstraints function:

```
 override func updateConstraints() {
    if !did_update_constraints {
        //prevent labels from being compressed below intrinsic height but also from taking too much height
        NSLayoutConstraint.autoSetPriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired){
            self.feedback_title.autoSetContentHuggingPriorityForAxis(.Vertical)
            self.feedback_title.autoSetContentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis(.Vertical)

            self.feedback_box.autoSetContentHuggingPriorityForAxis(.Vertical)
            self.feedback_box.autoSetContentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis(.Vertical)
        }

        //height constraints
        feedback_title.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: standard_height_width)


        //feedback_title constraints
        feedback_title.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Leading)
        feedback_title.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Trailing, relation: NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual)
        feedback_title.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Top)

        //feedback_box constraints
        feedback_box.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: feedback_title, withOffset: 10, relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)
        feedback_box.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Leading)
        feedback_box.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Trailing, relation: NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual)
        feedback_box.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewMargin(.Bottom)

        did_update_constraints = true

    }

    super.updateConstraints()
```

View hierarchy debugger:
[image]

Tableview code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        return setupDescriptionCell(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    case 1:
        return setupFeedbackCell(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    case 2:
        return setupStatsCell(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    case 3:
        return setupSurveyCell(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    default:
        return setupDefaultCell(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}


func setupFeedbackCell(tableView : UITableView, indexPath : NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cell_IDs[1], forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedbackCell

    //in the future download feedback in view did load and adjust here

    return cell
}
```

Comment: where does `feedback_title` and `feedback_box` get instantiated?

Comment: Edited to answer your question!

Comment: How do you define where they sit in your contentView?

Comment: Ok edited once again

Comment: That makes more sense.  Have you looked at the view hierarchy debugger in XCode to see if the views are there or not?

Comment: Is your `updateConstraints` even called when you don't add that additional label?

Comment: @Sulthan yes the updateConstraints is called.

Comment: @Jon Brooks Looking at the view hierarchy both UILabel's are there within the content view and seem to be in the appropirate position.

Comment: So it's just that the text isn't in the labels?  This is sort of a non-standard way of building one of these things.  Whats the reason for not using a Storyboard?  You might also try setting the text in `tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`.  Maybe you're setting the text too early.

Comment: @JonBrooks Sorry actually the UILabel's themselves are not appearing in the view hierarchy debugger. They're there but not appearing. I'll post a picture.

Comment: Why do you say it's non-traditional? I feel a lot of custom cells are made in code. I can't use Storyboard because the type of cell I'm displaying depends on the user's status. I don't want to preset the cells with content, and I want to have custom cell types because some of the types get pretty complicated (don't want to be adding subviews directly in the TableViewController).

Comment: Please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Hey, there's a whole bunch of important stuff you're not telling us. What's all that dump in the console about not even being able to load the nib? You've got serious stuff going wrong here that you don't even mention in your question.

Comment: Hi Matt the "not able to load nib" is related to my UITabBarController which is a previous page. I didn't notice that but thanks for pointing it out. It should be unrelated to this because it's a completely different view and something I just changed recently (after this problem was already occuring). I edited to include cellForRowAtindexPath

Comment: The "not able to load nib" issue is now fixed. Labels still don't appear in the content view.